# What is the relation between the cokernel with the kernel of the dual map of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying linear algebra and I am in front on questions like: What is the relation between the kernel of a linear map and the cokernel of the dual map?
What is the relation between theese objects and the existence of solution for the equation $f(x) = y$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll give a partial answer, since I also have no clue of the relation with the equation $f(x) = y$ as it is stated.

Let $T\colon V \to W$ be a linear map and $T^\ast\colon W^\ast \to V^\ast$ be the dual map. I claim that if the spaces have finite dimension, then ${\rm coker}(T) \cong \ker(T^\ast)$.

First of all, let's check that $\ker(T^\ast) = {\rm Ann}({\rm Im}(T))$. Just note that: $$w^\ast \in \ker(T^\ast) \iff T^\ast(w^\ast) = 0 \iff  w^\ast \circ T = 0 \iff w^\ast\bigg|_{{\rm Im}(T)} = 0 \iff w^\ast \in {\rm Ann}({\rm Im}(T)).$$

In finite dimension, we have $$\dim {\rm Im}(T) + \dim{\rm Ann}({\rm Im}(T)) = \dim W,$$ you can check this in page $124$ of Flavio Coelho's linear algebra book, which I'm sure you know (hue BR!).

Putting all of this together, we have: $$\dim{\rm coker}(T) = \dim \frac{W}{{\rm Im}(T)} = \dim W - \dim {\rm Im}(T) = \dim {\rm Ann}({\rm Im}(T)) = \dim \ker(T^\ast),$$ so we have the isomorphism. I believe strongly that we'll have problems in infinite dimension.

Comment: dear Ivo, I am sorry but I don't know the notation Ann, what it means? Thanks for the answer, I am doing an extense review of some subjects and I am trying to understand somethings in a deep way. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: The notation indicates the annihilator of set: the collection of the linear functionals that are zero on the set. The annihilator of a subset of a vector space is always a subspace of the dual space.

Comment: Glad to help! ${}{}$

Comment: What was confusing me is that I never heard about the annihilator. I study by Kostrikin and he did not mention it yet. I was trying to do this isomorphism with the notion of inner product, that works, but is needed to appeal for something that is neither always natural.
Thanks again.

Comment: Note that the isomorphism is not canonical, whatever way you construct it.

Comment: Back to the party: probably OP realized this himself ages ago, but the keyword regarding the relation with the equation $f(x)=y$ is "Fredholm's alternative" (and makes much more geometric sense when you have inner products). See the Appendix about differential operators on Besse's *Einstein Manifolds* book.